# Filter elements within object in DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table which contains objects looking like the following:

```
{
    'username': ...,
    'subscriptions': [
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

And I would like to filter subscriptions for each user based on some criteria, and get back the objects which have subscriptions matching the criteria, but filter those objects so that only the matching subscriptions are present.

If a user has subscribed to 50 things, but only 3 of them match, I would like to get back an object where the `subscriptions' field is only 3 elements long. I also need the other information contained in the object.

To give a more specific example, suppose that I have two elements in my table:

```
{
    'username': 'alice',
    'subscriptions': [
        1,
        2
     ],
     'email': 'alice@a.com'
},
{
    'username': 'bob',
    'subscriptions': [
        2,
        3
    ],
    'email': 'bob@a.com'
}
```

And I would like to filter to get the subscription `1'. I would like to get back

```
{
    'username': 'alice',
    'subscriptions': [
        1
    ],
    'email': 'alice@a.com'
}
```

Or perhaps some other structure which contains all the necessary information (and no other information in order to save bandwidth).

I believe I can do this with scan(), but I do not know the specifics.

Comment: Would you be interested in Java code? I know it is tagged as python. But I have only Java code.

Comment: It would still be useful